# Integrating an Unbounded Function on a Bounded Interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

We have the function $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx$. This definite integral evaluates to $2$ via the substitution method. Since the function $\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}$ is unbounded on the interval $(0,2)$, it is not Riemann integrable. But then, how are we able to integrate it and obtain a finite value?

Comment: Where did you get the idea unbounded means not integrable?

Comment: @NinadMunshi https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125b/ch1.pdf page 4. The first sentence of the paragraph after definition 1.3

Comment: By default Riemann integral deals with bounded functions on a closed and bounded interval. If one wants to deal with unbounded functions or unbounded intervals or a combination of both then one uses *improper* Riemann integrals which are defined as limits of Riemann integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote from the [textbook](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/m125b/ch1.pdf) you yourself posted in the comments, this is a kind of *improper integral*. Per Definition 1.67:

> Suppose that $f: (a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integral on $[c, b]$ for every $a < c < b$. Then the improper integral of $f$ on $[a, b]$ is
> $$\int_a^b f = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{a + \epsilon}^b f$$

For the integral you've given, the limit is defined and, indeed, finite, and hence the value of the integral is equal to that limit value.